# How to get the Html control Id dynamycally in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, html, dom

Here I need to create check boxes dynamically in a dynamic grid in asp.net web application, and I used the following code to do the sane, and then  I need to retrieve these Id's using the Find Control-`((CheckBox)GrdShiftDetails.FindControl(Convert.ToString(vStrchkboxId))).Checked`
But showing the error message like

> Null reference(object reference not set to an instance of an object)

So please help me to solve this issue.

```
if (GrdShiftDetails.Rows[VintCurrentRow].Cells[coloumcount].Text != "00:00-00:00") {
            CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
            chk.ID = "chk" + VintCurrentRow + coloumcount;
            chk.Checked = true;
            chk.Text = GrdShiftDetails.Rows[VintCurrentRow].Cells[coloumcount].Text;
            GrdShiftDetails.Rows[VintCurrentRow].Cells[coloumcount].Controls.Add(chk);
            // GrdShiftDetails.Rows[grdRow].Cells[coloumcount]
        }
        else {              
            CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
            chk.ID = "chk" + VintCurrentRow + coloumcount;
            chk.Checked = false;
            chk.Text = GrdShiftDetails.Rows[VintCurrentRow].Cells[coloumcount].Text;
            GrdShiftDetails.Rows[VintCurrentRow].Cells[coloumcount].Controls.Add(chk);
        }
    }
```

Comment: what line is giving you an error?

Answer (score 0):

Add a

```
if(GrdShiftDetails.Rows.Count > 0 && GrdShiftDetails.Columns.Count > 0)
{

// your code
(GrdShiftDetails.Rows[VintCurrentRow].Cells[coloumcount].Text != "00:00-00:00") {
            CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
            chk.ID = "chk" + VintCurrentRow + coloumcount;
            chk.Checked = true;
            chk.Text = GrdShiftDetails.Rows[VintCurrentRow].Cells[coloumcount].Text;
            GrdShiftDetails.Rows[VintCurrentRow].Cells[coloumcount].Controls.Add(chk);
            // GrdShiftDetails.Rows[grdRow].Cells[coloumcount]
        }
        else {              
            CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
            chk.ID = "chk" + VintCurrentRow + coloumcount;
            chk.Checked = false;
            chk.Text = GrdShiftDetails.Rows[VintCurrentRow].Cells[coloumcount].Text;
            GrdShiftDetails.Rows[VintCurrentRow].Cells[coloumcount].Controls.Add(chk);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach (GridViewRow objRow in GrdShiftDetails.Rows)
{
   TableCell cCheckCell = new TableCell();
   CheckBox chkCheckBox = new CheckBox();
   cCheckCell.Controls.Add(chkCheckBox);

   objRow.Cells.Add(cCheckCell);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to find the CheckBox you added:
Try this:

//assuming vStrchkboxId is the required ID of CheckBox

```
   for (int i = 0; i < GrdShiftDetails.Rows.Count; i++)
       if(((CheckBox)GrdShiftDetails.FindControl(Convert.ToString(vStrchkboxId))).Checked)
           //do something here.
```